# Installing a graphics library on linux

Tags: linux, graphics, installation

I'm not a linux expert, and I'm trying to install a 2D graphics library on Ubuntu 10.10.  I need to make a 2D display and after a little online research, GooCanvas seems like it will fit the bill.

I'm frustrated because it simply won't install and I don't get what I am supposed to do.

Here's what I did.

```
1> git clone git://git.gnome.org/goocanvas   #built a goocanvas directory

2> cd goocanvas

3> ls
AUTHORS         ChangeLog     demo                 goocanvas.doap  NEWS    src
autogen.sh      configure.in  docs                 MAINTAINERS     po      TODO
autom4te.cache  COPYING       goocanvas-2.0.pc.in  Makefile.am     README

4> less README  #here's what it says
To build it run './configure' and 'make'. To run the demo cd into 'demo' and
run './demo'. (Or run ./simple-demo for the very simple demo, or ./mv-demo
for the model-view demo.)


5> ./configure   # error: bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

6> find . -name "configure*" -print  #there aren't any other configure scripts?
```

'make;  and 'make install' don't work either.

OK, I'm frustrated.  Why does it say run configure if there isn't one?  How do I install this thing?

Does anyone know an easy to use graphics library for ubuntu that will actually work.  and can be easily installed?

Comment: what do you need exactly ? a display library (a library that handle creating a window and displaying a bitmap/pixmap for you) ? a stateless canvas library (let you draw primitives and text easily) ? a stateful canvas library (give it your objects and it will draw them) ? a widget library (a collection of interactive objects like buttons, textboxes & menus) ? a combination of them ? "graphical library" means so much differents things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know an easy to use graphics library for ubuntu that will actually work. 
>   and can be easily installed?

What is wrong with the big ones:

1. Qt
2. gtk
3. [EFL (The Enlightenment libs)](http://www.enlightenment.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I needed someone to point me to a different library.  I was able to get GTK to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/), which is usually assumed when talking about GTK, is a good 2D library.  Installing should be easy as this will be in your distributions repository (from the command line as root run `apt-get install libcairo2-dev`).

Now that I think about it - your new enough to Linux not to look at your repository for software first - learn to do that!  [I checked](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=goocanvas&searchon=names&suite=maverick&section=all) and found Ubuntu universe already has goocanvas, just `apt-get install libgoocanvas-dev` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Their instructions are out of date, execute the `autogen.sh` file first. You'll need the `gtk-doc-tools` and some other packages to support compiling things.

Edit 1:
Looks like it needs GTK 3.0, glib 2.28+, and Cairo 1.1+ - those are pretty modern. I'm not sure what Ubuntu 10.10 has them (I'm on 10.04), launch `Synaptic Package Manager` and search for `libgtk` the header files are in dev packages.

Edit 2:
What sort of graphics package are you looking for? SDL may work, or Cairo.

Comment: I want to show the motion of basic objects and physics.  GTK seems to be the most promising.  I even got PyGTK to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using SDL
If you want to use graphics.h on Ubuntu platform you need to compile and install libgraph. It is the implementation of turbo c graphics API on Linux using SDL.

It is not very powerful and suitable for production quality application, but it is simple and easy-to-use for learning purpose.

You can download it from http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/libgraph/libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz.

First install build-essential by typing

sudo apt-get install build-essential

Intall some additional packages by typing

sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 \

guile-1.8-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \

libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \

libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \

libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev

Now extract the downloaded libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz file.

Goto extracted folder and run following command

./configure

make

sudo make install

sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib

Now you can use #include on ubuntu platform

Compile it using gcc demo.c -o demo -lglut -lGL

```
    /*  demo.c*/
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
void setup() {   glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); }
void display()
   {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glRectf(-0.75f,0.75f, 0.75f, -0.75f);
      glutSwapBuffers();
   }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     glutInit(&argc, argv);
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
     glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
     glutCreateWindow("Hello World");

     setup();
     glutDisplayFunc(display);
     glutMainLoop();
     return 0;
  }
```

Run it using ./demo

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: We have developed a 2d Graphics library and Windowing System(GWS): https://github.com/MnMInfoTech/GWS